# On click ajax post request not working on click of cell in two tables as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Capturing table id and cell text by using below code.

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    var $row =$(e.target).closest("td");   // Find the row
    var $table_label= $row.text();
    //alert($table_label);
    var $table_id=$(this).closest("table").attr('id');
    if($(this).attr('style'))
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
      else
    $(this).css('background', '#309');



   tableText($table_label,$table_id); //this is ajax function
});
```

**Ajax funciton:**

```
$test_table1 = $('.test_table1')
$test_table2 = $('.test_table2')
function tableText(table_label,table_id) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({'label':'table', 'filter':{'table_id':table_id,'table_label':table_label}}),
        success: function(res, status, xhr){
            $test_table1.html(res['table1']);
            $test_table2.html(res['table2']);
        },
    });
    }
```

When I click on directly table2 it's working. When I click after clicking on table1 and then in table2 its not working. If I removed ajax function its working fine in both  cases.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `var $row =$(e.target).closest("td");  // Find the row` it should be `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("td").click(function () {` will bind events only to the a elements which are present in DOM.

`$(document).on("click", "td", function () {` will bind the event on the a elements which are not present at the time of binding event. This is called as event delegation.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

As per your ajax response, tr and td are added to the DOM after the binding of the element.

Instead of using  `$("td").click(function ()`, use `$(document).on("click", "td", function () {`